# LoginUser API access from Python

Tags: python, windows, authentication

Is there a way to call the following method from Python?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html). This example seems to work (Python 2.7):

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import HANDLE

# Example use of WinAPI
windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None, u"Example", u"Example", 0)

x = HANDLE()
print windll.advapi32.LogonUserW(u"Tupteq", None, u"passwd", 4, 0, pointer(x))
print windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
print x
```

In my case `GetLastError()` returned `1326` in case of bad password and `1327` when password was correct.

You may need to adjust values of `dwLogonType` and `dwLogonProvider`.